# Guards for module plugs?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Pardon the newbie question, but I've found plenty of examples of guarding ***function*** plugs like so:

```
plug :assign_welcome_message, "Hi!" when action in [:index, :show]
```

But I have found no examples of how to do this with ***module*** plugs:

```
plug Guardian.Plug.EnsurePermissions,
  handler: Mp.Api.AuthController,
  admin: [:dashboard] when action in [:protected_action]
```

Everywhere I seem to move `when action in [:protected_action]` either gives me a syntax error or an undefined function `when/2`. I know I'm doing something stupid but I can't see what!

Help!

---

`phoenix 1.1.4`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not stupid! Just a result of some syntactic sugar.

[Plugs take two arguments](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/readme.html#The-Plug-Conn), the second is an argument for options. In your example, you want to pass a keyword list as that options argument.

However, the [syntactic sugar that lets your drop the square brackets](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html#keyword-lists) only works if the keyword list is the last argument in the function.

Instead of

```
plug Guardian.Plug.EnsurePermissions,
  handler: Mp.Api.AuthController,
  admin: [:dashboard] when action in [:protected_action]
```

Try the explicit keyword list syntax:

```
plug Guardian.Plug.EnsurePermissions,
  [handler: Mp.Api.AuthController,
  admin: [:dashboard]] when action in [:protected_action]
```

Comment: This gives me the same compile error in my router pipeline, but works in the controller. Any ideas why? Using phoenix 1.3.0

Comment: @Johannes I am having the same issue. did you find  a solution?

Comment: If you look at the source code, `Phoenix.Controller.Pipeline` is programmed to compile guards (like `Plug.Builder`) but `Phoenix.Router` is not.